# Binding DataGrid to ObservableCollection of ModelWrapper<Model>

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml, datagrid

**Auto-Generating Columns for the Properties of a Wrapped-Object**

I am wanting to have AutoGeneratedColumns="true" but my I'm not sure how to do this with this ModelWrapper design. (I'm following the early stages of PluralSight.com's "Advanced Model Treatment" course).

My `<datagrid>` in a working state (This has manually defined columns, but I want autogenerated columns - while persisting with this ModelWrapper pattern):

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="0"
          Grid.RowSpan="2"
          Grid.Column="1"
          DockPanel.Dock="Top"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Segments}"
          SelectionUnit="FullRow" 
          AutoGenerateColumns="False">      

         <DataGrid.Columns>
             <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Width="1*" Binding="{Binding Model.Name}"/>
             <DataGridTextColumn Header="Notes" Width="2*" Binding="{Binding Model.Notes}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>

</DataGrid>
```

**Note:** that the DataContext for the `<datagrid>` above (i.e. the associated ViewModel) exposes an `ObservableCollection<ModelWrapper<Segment>>` called `Segments`.

Here is my ModelWrapper class that is used to wrap a basic class with only CLR properties (I hazard a guess the problem is not here - or in my model definition further below):

Note: `Observable` implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

```
internal class ModelWrapper<T> : Observable
{
    public ModelWrapper(T model)
    {
        if (model == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(model));
        Model = model;
    }

    public T Model { get; }

    protected void SetValue<TValue>(TValue value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var propertyInfo = Model.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
        var currentValue = propertyInfo.GetValue(Model);
        if (Equals(currentValue, value)) return;
        propertyInfo.SetValue(Model, currentValue);
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
    }

    protected TValue GetValue<TValue>([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var propertyInfo = Model.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
        return (TValue) propertyInfo.GetValue(Model);
    }
}
```

Here is the model class that is wrapped by the ModelWrapper:

```
internal class Segment
{
    public string Notes { get; set; }
    public string Name  { get; set; }
}
```

If I set `AutoGenerateColumns` to `True`, then I only get one column with the Header `...Model` (i.e. `ToString()`-ing the Model object).

I've rushed ahead of the course and am trying to implement something with the ModelWrapper pattern. Can I autogenerate the columns, as per the properties of the ordinaryCLRobject?

How? What and I doing wrong? ... thanks in advance. :-)

Comment: _"my ModelWrapper design is causing issues with this"_ -- I'd guess even if you solve this issue, you'll find more down the road. Frankly, I don't get your design. It's inefficient (reflection), and while you don't explain how/where the `SetValue()` and `GetValue()` methods are called, I don't see how your design is better than the more conventional `INotifyPropertyChanged`-implementing base class used for the model itself, rather than some wrapper for the model. You should start by fixing your question to include a good [mcve], so it's more clear how you wound up painted into this corner.

Comment: The `ModelWrapper` extends Observable which implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`. ... I have been following PluralSight.com's "Advanced Model Treatment" course... (I haven't completed it yet.)

Comment: _"ModelWrapper extends Observable which implements INotifyPropertyChanged"_ -- yes, I inferred as much. But what's the point of `ModelWrapper`? It's the `Segment` class that should inherit `Observable`, and were it to, you wouldn't have your problem at all.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I was creating `ObservableCollections` of type `ModelWrapper` instead of, in my case, `SegmentWrapper : ModelWrapper<Segment>`.

I can then remove `Model.` from the binding path in my xaml columns, i.e.:

```
        <DataGrid.Columns>
             <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Width="1*" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
             <DataGridTextColumn Header="Notes" Width="2*" Binding="{Binding Notes}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
```